# What does $X(f)$ mean (where $X$ is a vector field and $f$ is a function?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-fields, tangent-spaces, tangent-bundle

What does $X(f)$ mean (where $X$ is a vector field and $f$ is a function?

What I am referring to is for example the section [Vector Field On Manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_field) in the Wikipedia article.

If a vector field $X$ is a map from a manifold $M$ to its tangent bundle $TM$ and a funcrion $f$ is a map $C^\infty(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, how can we create $X(f)$?

Do I interpret right that the $f$ is like an "argument" of $X$ here? I thought that if $f$ "returns" a scalar from $\mathbb{R}$, but the $X$ takes elements from the manifold $M$ as arguments, how can it take $f$ as an argument and what does it do with it?

I have also seen $X$ defined as a (linear) map $X :C^\infty(M) \rightarrow C^\infty(M)$ , which confuses me even more. How does that correspond to the other definition that uses $X: M \rightarrow TM$? If $C^\infty(M)$ means just infinitely-differentiable maps from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$, does that mean that what $X$ "returns" is still such a map?

**Summary:** I hope my question is clear. I am just confused about what $X$ takes as an argument (where does the argument live and what it is) and what $X$ returns and where does the outcome live. This confusion stems from seing an expression $X(f)$ which doesnt make sense to me.

Thank you.

Comment: $X$ must not only be a linear endomorphism on $C^\infty(M)$ but a *derivation*: for any two smooth functions $f,g$, one has that $X(fg) = X(f)g + f X(g)$. This captures the fact that if $X$ is a field, then $X(f)$ is the derivative of $f$ along $X$.

Comment: @Pedro Thank you! I know that, I just tried not to post too long question. But still, I dont get how $X$ can take $f, g$ one time as arguments and points $p \in M$ next time. That is what confuses me and what my question is about.

Comment: $X(f)$ is the function $p \in M \longmapsto (d_pf)(X(p))$ (basically, $X$ is a function with values in a space of functions: $X(f)$ is still a function on $M$ so can be evaluated. You can also take the viewpoint that it’s just a convenient notation and forget for the moment about the function $X: C^{\infty}(M) \rar C^{\infty}(M)$.

Comment: @Aphelli Thanks, I see! ...So the $d_p f$ is the directional derivative defined such that $d_p f(x) = Lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x + tv) - f(x)}{t}$?

Comment: @Aphelli Or the $d_p f(x)$ is NOT the directional derivative as I wrote above, but a differential, that is a linear map (also called pushforward) $T_p M \rightarrow T_f(p) N$? This second option makes more sense to me. (I am really sorry for how confused I am by all these notations.)

Comment: @Pedro If I remember correctly, then one way to define tangent spaces is via derivations and in that case the expression $X_p(f)$ is litteraly defined as the image of $f$ under $X_p$. I think that this is one reason for that notation. But I am not sure, can you confirm this?

Comment: Your confusion accounts for the fact that most people write $X_p$ rather than $X(p)$ for the value of $X$ at $p$. Then $\big(X(f)\big)(p) = X_p(f)$.

Comment: We're going around in circles here. We need an actual definition of the tangent bundle. There are numerous definitions. I think you should read a standard textbook on differentiable manifolds rather than relying on Wikipedia entries. But if you clarify which definition of $TM$ you're going to use, then there's room for discussion.

Comment: @TedShifrin Pedro's answer is correct independent of the definition of the tangent bundle, isn't it?

Comment: @Filippo This is very subtle. When you work with $C^1$ (rather than $C^\infty$) manifolds, for example, the space of derivations at $p$ is infinite-dimensional, so you certainly won’t recover the $n$-dimensional geometric tangent space, no.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry, I should have mentioned that I was referring to the answer **after** the recent edit: Now the answer only claims that each vector field defines a derivation and I think that this is true for all differentiable manifolds, i.e. manifolds where transition charts are only required to be differentiable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that $X$ must not only be a linear endomorphism on $C^\infty(M)$ but a *derivation*: for any two smooth functions $f,g$, one has that $X(fg) = X(f)g + f X(g)$. This captures the fact that if $X$ is a field, then $X(f)$ is the derivative of $f$ along $X$.

In case that $X$ is given as a map $X : M \longrightarrow TM$, you can define $X(f)$ as follows: for each $p\in M$, the tangent vector $X_p$ is just the datum of a vector (at the point $p$) so you may compute the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ along $X_p$:

$$X(f)_p = df_p(X_p).$$

This is linear on scalars (because $df_p$ is linear), and we have that

$$X(fg)_p = d(fg)_p(X_p) = f(p) dg_p(X_p) + g(p) df_p(X_p),$$

so this gives an assignment that turns a field $X : M\longrightarrow TM$
into a derivation $X : C^\infty(M) \longrightarrow C^\infty(M)$.

Comment: Thank you, this is amazing. Could you evaluate on how exactly is $df_p(X_p)$defined? Is it just a limit $lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac {f(p + t X_p) - f(p)}{t}$ where "along $X_p$ is the same as "in the direction of $X_p$"?

Comment: @TerezaTizkova The expression $p+tX_p$ is in general not defined. You seem to be assuming an affine structure.

Comment: @Filippo I would just like to know how $df_p(X_p)$ is defined. The expression above is what I was taught directional derivative is, I am aware that it seems weird in this case, but I cannot figure out or find the definition of $df_p(X_p)$.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova Take a chart $x$ defined on a neighbourhood of $p$. Then $$\mathrm d f_p=\mathrm d(f\circ x^{1})_{x(p)}\circ\mathrm d x_p$$where on the RHS the first differential is just the differential of a function from a subset of $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$ (i.e. an element of $L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R)$) and the definition of $\mathrm d x_p\in L(T_pM,\mathbb R^n)$ depends on the definition of the tangent space.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova But you will never need to choose a particular definition. The deeper reason is that the tangent bundle is only defined up to a natural bundle isomorphism...

Comment: I'm confused. The identity map $1$ is not a scalar-valued function. And certainly you get $0$ if you consider the constant map $1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Whoops. Can't fix it now. Maybe you can?

Comment: This is not an easy fix. You must first work in local coordinates $x=(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ and then prove that every derivation at $p$, say with $x(p)=0$, is given by $\sum a_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\Big|_p$ for some scalars $a_i$, which is a "geometric" tangent vector. The proof of this result requires bump functions and a little bit of work. I think it's time for the OP to pick a good textbook to read.